# Get excerpt using get_the_excerpt outside a loop

Tags: loop, excerpt

I have a code that call `get_the_title()` and it works, but `get_the_excerpt()` return empty. How can i make it work?

This code is inside a plugin called "WP Facebook Open Graph protocol". Here's the part i want to change:

```
if (is_singular('post')) {
  if (has_excerpt($post->ID)) {
    echo "\t<meta property='og:description' content='".esc_attr(strip_tags(get_the_excerpt($post->ID)))."' />\n";
  }else{
    echo "\t<meta property='og:description' content='". [?] ."' />\n";
  }
}else{
  echo "\t<meta property='og:description' content='".get_bloginfo('description')."' />\n";
}
```

Here, `has_excerpt` always fail, and `get_the_excerpt($post->ID)` don't work anymore (deprecated).

So, how can i display the excerpt there?

ps: I'm using "Advanced Excerpt" plugin as well

Comment: ok, got it using `my_excerpt($post->post_content, get_the_excerpt())` and using the `my_excerpt()` function from http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6961/using-wp-trim-excerpt-to-get-the-excerpt-outside-the-loop

Comment: Please add solution you came up with as an answer, so this doesn't haunt site as unanswered question. :)

Comment: Just use `the_post()` (it works on single post template too) function before you call `get_the_excerpt()` it will setup necessary data for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

got it using `my_excerpt($post->post_content, get_the_excerpt())` and using the `my_excerpt()` function from [Using wp_trim_excerpt to get the_excerpt() outside the loop](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6961/using-wp-trim-excerpt-to-get-the-excerpt-outside-the-loop)

Comment: Link-only answers are no good.  Copy the relevant code here.  When that link is broken, that site is down / gone, then this answer has no value.

Comment: It worked perfectly for me!

Answer (score 32):

I found this question when looking how to do this *without* the post object.

My additional research turned up this slick technique:

`$text = apply_filters('the_excerpt', get_post_field('post_excerpt', $post_id));`

Comment: This should be accepted as answer as it's the recommended way to pull data outside the loop. Also doesn't require any custom function or overriding of the `$post` global variable.

Comment: it return empty string.

Comment: @KyawTun - it works, so long as `$post_id` is set (what is the value of `$post_id`? AND `$post_id` is a valid, legitimate post ID.

Comment: @cale_b Thanks. I use get_posts query and get ID from the resulting array. The post object does have post_title, post_content, ID, etc. But not working.

Comment: If you need JUST the TEXT and not <p> tag which is included with the_excerpt filter, then use "get_the_excerpt" filter, so that above filter becomes:    $text = apply_filters('get_the_excerpt', get_post_field('post_excerpt', $post_id));  this will give you just the RAW text you can insert anywhere in your own markup.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. Remember: "the excerpt of the post. This is either a user-supplied excerpt, that is returned unchanged, or an automatically generated word-counted trimmed-down version of the full post content." Might work for the user-supplied one? I was looking for the automatically-generated excerpt.

Answer (score 22):

Since it seems you already have the post object you need the excerpt for, you can just force things to work:

```
setup_postdata( $post );
$excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
```

The `setup_postdata()` function will globalize the `$post` object and make it available for regular old loop function.  When you're inside the loop, you call `the_post()` and it sets things up for you ... outside of the loop you need to force it manually.

Comment: This works but: "You must pass a reference to the global `$post` variable, otherwise functions like `the_title()` don't work properly."
`global $post;$post = $post_object;setup_postdata( $post );$excerpt = get_the_excerpt();`

Comment: `setup_postdata($post);` FTW!!!!

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

Create a new function in functions.php and then call it from wherever.

```
function get_excerpt_by_id($post_id){
    $the_post = get_post($post_id); //Gets post ID
    $the_excerpt = $the_post->post_content; //Gets post_content to be used as a basis for the excerpt
    $excerpt_length = 35; //Sets excerpt length by word count
    $the_excerpt = strip_tags(strip_shortcodes($the_excerpt)); //Strips tags and images
    $words = explode(' ', $the_excerpt, $excerpt_length + 1);

    if(count($words) > $excerpt_length) :
        array_pop($words);
        array_push($words, '…');
        $the_excerpt = implode(' ', $words);
    endif;

    $the_excerpt = '<p>' . $the_excerpt . '</p>';

    return $the_excerpt;
}
```

[Here's a post describing the code.](http://www.uplifted.net/programming/wordpress-get-the-excerpt-automatically-using-the-post-id-outside-of-the-loop/)

Comment: Excellent find my friend. I've never understood why WordPress would have deprecated such a critical function. This is effectively rebuilding it from scratch, but it works. Given how often we use the excerpt outside the loop with features like social sharing plugins, it probably should have remained a part of the core.

Comment: EAMann's answer is a much better approach to this problem, and the should be considered the best practice. This approach is basically duplicating Core's internals instead of using the API.

Answer (score 9):

Now you can simply use the [`get_the_excerpt( $postID )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_excerpt/) function. 
Since: WordPress 4.5.0 introduced the `$post` parameter.

Comment: This should be new accepted answer since we are in WP 4.5 + era.

Comment: This won't work if the excerpt is empty as the `wp_trim_excerpt` filter will return the excerpt for the current post.

Comment: See https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/36934 for details on what @Dylan said

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't have the post object, here's a short function like the one from Withers.

```
function get_excerpt_by_id($post_id){
    $the_post = get_post($post_id);
    $the_excerpt = $the_post->post_excerpt; 
    return $the_excerpt;
}
```

Comment: But the asker has a post object as stated in the question.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, this method will return the manual excerpt but **won't** generate one if needed

Answer (score 1):

This is for when you want to use `get_the_excerpt()` outside the loop:

```
function custom_get_excerpt($post_id) {
    $temp = $post;
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    setup_postdata($post);

    $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();

    wp_reset_postdata();
    $post = $temp;

    return $excerpt;
}
```

Comment: This is the most direct way to do it.. Not sure it's great performance-wise though. You still get my +1

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to generate the excerpt automatically from the content in one line - you can use [`wp_trim_words`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words) function like this:

```
// 30 is the number of words ehere
$excerpt = wp_trim_words(get_post_field('post_content', $post_id), 30);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$trimexcerpt = get_the_content();
$shortexcerpt = wp_trim_words( $trimexcerpt, $num_words = 18, $more = '… ' ); 
echo $shortexcerpt;
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?