# How to define Og Meta Tags in header using conditions

Tags: php, conditional-tags

I'm trying to configure my Facebook Og meta tags in my header so I get a different result on the type of page I want. I've been hitting some road block that searching through google haven't been able to resolve, so I thought asking for help here.

This question comes in two parts, one about if statements and wordpress conditional tags. The second about the use of get_the_excerpt with those if statements.

Here I'm trying to set the default title. But I'm suspecting my issues are linked to my if statements.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php if( is_single() || is_page()){ 
echo get_the_title(); //for post and pages
}else{ if( is_home() || is_front_page() ){
echo "Predefined Name";  //force the name as default for the home / front page
}else{
echo wp_title //to get default title for all other types of pages
}
?>" />
```

For the page description i'm unsuccessfully also trying to get the excerpt using get_the_excerpt, but since i'm outside the loop, it doesn't work. I've been looking especially [here (Get excerpt using get_the_excerpt outside a loop)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26729/get-excerpt-using-get-the-excerpt-outside-a-loop) for help, but I'm not sure as to how to incorporate those.

```
    <meta property="og:description" content="<?php if (is_single() ){
        echo get_the_excerpt //to get the post's excerpt from outside the loop
    }else{ if( is_home() || is_front_page() ){
    echo "Predefined Description";  //doing this to force a default description
    }else{
        echo "Predefined Description"; //for all other pages
    } ?>" />
```

Comment: use `the_post();` just before the `get_the_excerpt()` function.

Comment: @sisir If you wanna post a solution I can vote it, but the question also revolves around the if statements, if you wanna offer your input on those too in the answer it could be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like your elseif statement isn't correct. 
try something like :

```
if ( is_single() || is_page() ) {
echo get_the_title();
} elseif ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {
echo "Predefined Name";
} else {
echo wp_title;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php