# Pull in excerpt with shortcode

Tags: shortcode, excerpt

I am working with a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/radio-station) that provides a shortcode with only a couple of parameters. I'm using `[list-shows]` shortcode. I would like to also pull in an excerpt of the content.

I was able to add in the thumbnail to the output, but not the content, which seems to be referred to in the `atts` of the other shortcodes as `show_desc`. You can see the output on this [page](http://www.kzmuradio.org/kzmu-programs/)

Here is the code for the shortcode. Apologies for my ignorance. Learning curve.

```
/* 
 * Shortcode for displaying a list of all shows * Since 2.0.0 
 */
function station_shortcode_list_shows($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'genre' => '',
        'show_desc' => 1
                    ), $atts));

    //grab the published shows
    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'offset' => 0,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post_type' => 'show',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'show_active',
                'value' => 'on',
            )
        )
    );

    if ($genre != '') {
        $args['genres'] = $genre;
    }

    $shows = get_posts($args);

    //if there are no shows saved, return nothing
    if (!$shows) {
        return false;
    }

    $output = '';

    $output .= '<div id="station-show-list">';
    $output .= '<ul>';
    foreach ($shows as $show) {


        $output .= '<li>' . get_the_post_thumbnail($show->ID, 'thumbnail') . '<a href="' . get_permalink($show->ID) . '">' . get_the_title($show->ID) . '</a></li>';

        $output .= '</li>';
    }
    $output .= '</ul>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at how `[dj-widget]` shortcode is handled you will get an idea of how to implement plugin authors' idea of showing post description.

```
            if($show_desc) {
                $desc_string = station_shorten_string(strip_tags($show->post_content), 20);
                $output .= '<span class="on-air-show-desc">'.$desc_string.'</span>';
            }
```

insert this between `$output .= '<li>...'` and `$output .= '</li>';`

Please NOTE: There might be a better way to show actual post excerpt instead trying to generate one based on post content. More [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26729/get-excerpt-using-get-the-excerpt-outside-a-loop).