# Strip div From Excerpt

Tags: functions, excerpt

I have the_excerpt() in a specific page, I need to strip a div and keep the text, but only in the excerpt of that page.

I believe I need to create a function with custom excerpt, but I don't how to do it. Tested several solutions I found here and nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just needed in one place, you could use the following:

```
echo wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_excerpt() );
```

Keep in mind, using the custom excerpt field will automatically remove all tags. Creating an excerpt automatically from the post content will not.

If you want more control, you can use `wp_trim_excerpt()` or `wp_trim_words()`.

See: [Using wp_trim_excerpt to get the_excerpt() outside the loop](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6961/using-wp-trim-excerpt-to-get-the-excerpt-outside-the-loop)

In your case, it would look like this:

```
echo wp_strip_all_tags( wp_trim_words( get_the_excerpt(), 60, '[...]' ) );
```

[`wp_trim_words()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words) allows you to pass in the text source, number of words, and the more text. You can remove the more text by setting this to `false`.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work. I have this.
<?php if( $content_source == 'content' ) the_content(); else the_excerpt() ?>

Comment: What happens when you use this? `<?php if( $content_source == 'content' ) { the_content(); } else { echo wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_excerpt() ); } ?>`

Comment: Wonderful! Works great! Is there a way to limit the number of words in that particular line?! I am asking, because it strips the div, but not the text that's inside the div.

Comment: Updating my answer to include this.